# Succinct Way Of Creating Multiple Grouped Histograms

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm creating a series of grouped histograms with matplotlib like so:

```
movies.pivot(columns='genre', values='comedy_score').plot.hist()
plt.show()

movies.pivot(columns='genre', values='suspense_score').plot.hist()
plt.show()

movies.pivot(columns='genre', values='drama_score').plot.hist()
plt.show()
```

Pivoting the data frame gives me a nice grouping and legend according to genre, but I'd like to know if there is a way to create multiple histograms without having to type out a histogram for each score.

In other words, is there an equivalent of `df.hist()` that supports grouping data like the above examples?

Comment: Please provide a minimal dataset for clarity/reproducibility.

Comment: Seaborn's [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) creates multiple subplots in the way you describe. Your data would need to be converted to "long form" (via `pd.melt`).

Comment: @JohanC thanks for this, I'll have to look into this approach.